# How to run a simple socket server that allows incoming connections?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, sockets

I am trying to build a very simple socket server in JAVA that my Flash application can listen to. [I am using this tutorial](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-8000.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ced). Everything seems to be working - the JAVA code is compiled and the server is running.

My question is: how can external applications send messages to this server using just an IP address and a port number? My goal is that flash can listen to socket messages sent by an external application.

The Java code:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 

class SimpleServer { 
    private static SimpleServer server; 
    ServerSocket socket; 
    Socket incoming; 
    BufferedReader readerIn; 
    PrintStream printOut; 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int port = 8080; 

        try { 
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { 
            // Catch exception and keep going. 
        } 

        server = new SimpleServer(port); 
    } 


    private SimpleServer(int port) { 
        System.out.println(">> Starting SimpleServer"); 

        try { 
            socket   = new ServerSocket(port); 
            incoming = socket.accept(); 
            readerIn = new BufferedReader(
                           new InputStreamReader(
                               incoming.getInputStream())); 
            printOut = new PrintStream(incoming.getOutputStream()); 

            printOut.println("Enter EXIT to exit.\r"); 
            out("Enter EXIT to exit.\r"); 
            boolean done = false; 

            while (!done) { 
                String str = readerIn.readLine(); 

                if (str == null) { 
                    done = true; 
                } else { 
                    out("Echo: " + str + "\r"); 

                    if(str.trim().equals("EXIT"))
                        done = true; 
                } 

                incoming.close(); 
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println(e); 
        } 
    } 

    private void out(String str) { 
        printOut.println(str); 
        System.out.println(str); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You have received 4 different answers to you question. Did one of these anwer your question?

Comment: I greatly appreciate the answers but I haven't yet had time to build a new server test!

Answer (score 1):

By not specifying an IP address for your socket, it will listen on `0.0.0.0` (all interfaces).
In fact, that will usually be your computer's IP / the server's IP.

Assuming that your application runs on your computer at home, there are three cases that cover most of the connection situations:

**Connecting from the same machine**:
Use 127.0.0.1:8080

**Connecting from the same LAN (e.g. your brother's PC)**:
Use your LAN IP (e.g. 192.168.1.4:8080)

**Connecting from WAN (outside your routers LAN) (internet e.g.)**:
Use your WAN IP.(e.g. 84.156.74.194). There are plenty websites, that tell you your WAN IP like [this](http://www.whatsmyip.org/)
*You may have to setup your router, to forward the port 8080 to your PC*


For simple connection tests, one could use a telnet client.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand correctly your problem description, but if you create the server in Java, it listens to its port and not your Flash application. If you want your Flash application to wait for messages from other applications, it must have a server role and listen to a TCP port the same way as this Java server does.

You can connect to and test the given Java server easily by `telnet` program (available in all operating systems) by providing a host name or an IP address and a port as parameters:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
```

Any other application can connect in a similar way, using just a hostname/IP address and a port. For example in Java, you can create a client socket:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the point of client/server socket applications.

If you are building the socket **server** (with whatever programming language you chose), you will then need to connect with (a) socket **client**(s) to this server. After a connection is successfully established (persistent) between the client and the server, you can start what ever kind of communication you have implemented between them.

The server always acts as the passive, the client as active part in a socket server/client constellation.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking the [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-8000.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ced) that you are referring to. In that, the procedure to create a stand-alone server is mentioned which is the code that you have pasted as well.

According to the link, the application acts as the client and uses the `XMLSocket` methods to connect to this server. This application is the flash application that you are talking about. As mentioned in the link, by using the following code any flash application can connect and talk to the server:

```
    var xmlsock:XMLSocket = new XMLSocket(); 
    xmlsock.connect("127.0.0.1", 8080);
    xmlsock.send(xmlFormattedData);
```

When you mention

> My goal is that flash can listen to socket messages sent by an external application.

its actually the flash application that is the client and it cannot listen unless programmed to act as a server. I hope this provides some clarity!